# Open firewall ports on MSSQL for SCOM

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, scom

I'm trying to figure out which ports I have to open on my MSSQL-Server to let the SCOM (System center operations manager) connect successfully.

I've tried:

`disable the domain network` firewall -> `SCOM` successfully connect.

new rule `allow TCP inbound ports 1-65535` -> `SCOM` successfully connect.

If I just enable `port 1433,1434` no connection can be established (from [Technet.microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/6c3dc8ff-4f66-4c73-9c9e-4ca948cde3ff/scom-2012-installing-operations-manager-database-on-server-behind-a-firewall?forum=operationsmanagerdeployment))

Which ports do I have to open?

I'm using `SCOM 2012` with `MSSQL 2014` on `win Server 2012R2`

Comment: Have you tried to telnet port 1433 to verify that your firewall rule is set up correctly? Are you sure no-one [changed the default ports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938)?

Comment: ive installed telnet server and client. telnet does not work using command `telnet msql-server 1433`. neither does when both firewalls are `disabled`. neither does on default port 23.

i just installed mssql as well as scom, with all default values. im using a `named instance on mssql server`

Comment: Are you currently trying to install SCOM?  Or are you talking about having a SCOM agent on the SQL server connect back to the SCOM Management Server?

Comment: Im installing SCOM, in the installation process i disabled the firewall. success. then enabled firewall, set the port rules, started OpearionsManager (running on another virtual machine), and it said: "connection to server" forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to configure the static ports for IP1, IP2, IPAll,
Erase the `0` at `Dynamic Ports` and set `TCP Ports` to `1433`, however, Im using a named instance.

also open firewall ports

> Once you have static ports, you'll need to enable access to 1433 TCP and 1434 UDP.
>   (Katherine Villyard)

See Screen Shots for configuration details.

[image: Configuration 1]
[image: Configuration 2]

Answer (score 2):

Since 2008, SQL Server answers on dynamic ports by default.  You can set static ports in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

To turn Dynamic Ports off, erase the 0 that appears on the right side, above the port number (in this case, 1433).

Once you have static ports, you'll need to enable access to 1433 TCP and 1434 UDP.

[image]

Comment: i did configure it as you said, restarted the mssql-server. no success. do i have to "enable" IP1 & IP2, because now it is set to `enabled - no`?

Comment: the connetion cannot be establish. The Operations Manger Console says "connection to Server", until i disable the Firewall at my MSSQLserver.